# Angular.js routing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

Angular is working as I can see the `{{ text }}` but I can't seem to get the `ng-view` to display.

My code is:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='app'>
    <div class="main_container" ng-controller="MainController">
    <span ng-cloak>{{text}}</span>
    <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <!-- modules -->
    <script src='app.js'></script>
    <!-- controllers -->
    <script src='MainController.js'></script>
    <script src='home.js'></script>     
  </body>
</html>
```

home.js:

```
app.controller('home', function($scope) {
    $scope.words = 'It works!';
});
```

MainController:

```
app.controller('MainController',function($scope){
    $scope.text = 'Hello World!';
});
```

home.html:

```
<div ng-controller="home">
    <h3>{{ words }}</h3>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/index',{
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'home'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/index' 
        });
     //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

edit:
It seems to work in plunker but when I open the file in chrome I get the following error:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load {{file location}}.  Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: you don't need to hardcode your controller in `home.html`, it is already loaded with the view. Any errors in the console?

Comment: Your home controller should be named HomeController so you are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ng-controller` attribute on your root element in home.html because you are already defining the controller for that template when you set up your `$routeProvider`.  Beyond that your code looks good.  If you really want to get ahead of the game, though, I would recommend using [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) if you plan to do any advanced routing in your application.  It is much more robust and easier to work with than Angular's ngRoute, widely used, and well-documented.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is working fine !! there may be problem on which file to load first so please take care of the order of the files added in your HTML

Here is the working plunker with your code. here ng-view loads with no problem

http://embed.plnkr.co/oNADizOltrGitbWTWNXf/preview

Hope this helps!!!